# In flutter, what is the difference between variables declared in the State class and in the build method of that state?

Tags: flutter, dart

In flutter while dealing with stateful widgets, we can declare variables at 2 places inside the state class shown using `variable_1` and `variable_2`.

```
class StatefulWidget_STATE_class extents State<className>{
    final int variable_1 = 2;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
    final int variable_2 = 2;
    }
}
```

What is the difference between the two declarations and when should one be used over the other?

Comment: variable2 will be defined for each build of the screen. variable1 will be defined only one time when StatefulWidget_STATE_class is generating.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it a bad practice to declare variables in build method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62670271/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-declare-variables-in-build-method)

Comment: But isn't the state rebuild everytime something changes. In that case, everytime the state rebuilds, won't variable_1 be redeclared ? @Akif

Comment: A variable declared in a function body is local that function.  An instance variable instead will persist its value for the lifetime of the object.  The distinction doesn't matter in your trivial example since your variables are `final` (and even could be `const`).  The distinction would matter if you wanted to mutate your `State`.

Comment: Let's consider that I am to mutate my state. In that case, where should I declare my variables for most efficiency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable in your state is saved in your state. The variable in your function is local to your function.

That means the variable in your function will be destroyed when your function is finished and will be recreated and reinitialized every time the function is called.

Therefor, if you want this variable to hold your state between function calls, it need to be outside the function. In this case, in your state class.

This isn't about efficiency. If you want something that is only important to this one run of the build function, make it a local variable. If you want something that keeps it's value even when build is called multiple times (for example with every state change) you need to put it into your state class instead.

Generally speaking, confine your variable to the least amount of visibility that still fullfils it's purpose and then let the compiler worry about efficiency. The lower the visibility of the variable, the easier it is for the compiler to optimize it.

Comment: I think I understood it from your explanation. To make sure, tell me if this interpretation of mine is correct or not:
If i create 2 separate pages, page1 and page 2 and I can navigate from page 1 to page2(and back). Now if I declare my variables in the state class(of page 1) instead of its build function, it would retain that state if i navigate to page 2 and then back to page 1

Comment: That depends on how you build the navigation. But if you put it in the state, it *could* survive navigation when you build it that way, while a local variable in the build function *cannot* survive navigation, no matter how you build it.

Comment: Try to understand the difference between a state variable and a local variable. A state or class variable is outside any method or function and belongs to the class. A local variable is transient and only exists (and visible) within the curly braces of a method or even a statement such as the `if` statement.